# Vocal part for my range

Tags: technique, vocal-range

I have a vocal range that spans from D2 to D6 and while I love singing normal tenor part what would fit my voice best?

Comment: Sing a bunch of basic songs (Christmas carols, children's songs, national anthems, etc.). What octaves do you sing them in? There's your answer.